# Autocomplete disabled in a prompt

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, prompt, autocorrect

I am currently working on a webapp for iPhone with PhoneGap. I am creating a game where players have to remember their vocabulary. In a part of my code, the iPhone is displaying a prompt in js and the player has to write a word correctly. 
My code :

```
var motPense = prompt('Which word are you thinking about ' + localStorage.joueur2 +' ?');
```

As I am working in a game where you have to remember your vocabulary, I want to disable "Autocapitalize", "Autocomplete" and "Autocorrect" such as in an input like this:

```
<input type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
```

Is there any way to do this in a prompt, or I will have to display a  with an input inside?

Thank you.

PS : Sorry for my approximative english

Comment: What browser is giving you autocomplete in a prompt?

Comment: Mobile Safari works like this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to build your own prompt out of DOM elements; a normal JavaScript prompt() is generated with native code that you can't style or modify.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, I'll try do to it with CSS3 transitions and HTML.